# How do I find the package for the time conversion implicits in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

On the official API page, I've searched for "time", but can't find the class. I looked at all methods on [RichLong](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.RichLong) and [RichInt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.RichInt), but can't find the methods.

I'm specifically talking about the methods that convert between int/long to some kind of rich object:

```
2 hours + 12 seconds
```

Note I'm not asking *what* the package is, I want to know how to find it.

Comment: The API for `scala.Long` shows `def +(x: Int): Long`.  I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't in the standard Scala API.  Are you using the scala-time wrapper for JodaTime?  If so, that would tell you where to look.  In general, if you know which import enables the capability, it helps a lot when trying to find documentation!

If you know a method name, you can click on the little letters at the top of the left panel, just below the search text field in ScalaDoc--this will bring up a list of everything in the docs with that name, including methods (and tell you how to find it).

If a class doesn't have a method itself, you can use Scala to tell you what class it's getting converted to:

```
def whoHasSize[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => { def size: Int }) = ev(a).getClass.getName

scala> whoHasSize("fish")
res1: java.lang.String = scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
```

So here you see that the string `"fish"` does not itself have a `size` method; instead, that's been granted by the `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps` method.  You could do the same thing to find out about `seconds`.

Finally, stew's answer is probably what you were really looking for!

Comment: I know what the method's name is - it's seconds or hours or minutes. I don't know how to search in the official docs by method. I really thought it was in the official Scala API.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil - I have added information on how to search and tell what you've got.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-Xlog-implicits` flag to have the compiler show you where it is finding the  implicit conversions.

Comment: I *think* both IDEA and the eclipse plugins have balloon tips for this also: [IntelliJ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/289036);  [scala-IDE Helium](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html)